# In Angular2 Unit Testing what replaced the deprecated provide?

Tags: angular

I am writing unit tests for my Angular 2 application and to mock out injected services we're using provide to tell the test to use our mocked class instead of the code behind. However in IntelliJ I keep getting a warning telling me that provide was deprecated and that I shouldn't really be using it. However the documentation doesn't exist and no matter how hard I search I can't seem to find anyone else asking this question or using anything else.

So what replaced provide?

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
describe('Dashboard Component', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      provide(ProjectService, {
        useClass: MockProjectService
      })
    ];
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
  provide(ProjectService, {
    useClass: MockProjectService
  })
```

use object literal syntax:

```
  {
    provide: ProjectService, 
    useClass: MockProjectService
  }
```